# java.lang.NullPointerException in FilterChain doFilter Methid

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, filter, struts

I have added a filter in `web.xml` deployment descriptor. But whenever a request is coming to the server, the filter throws a `NullPointerException`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:427)
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getIndexedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:340) 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:664) 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:715) 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.setProperty(BeanUtilsBean.java:884) 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean.populate(BeanUtilsBean.java:811) 
org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:298) 
org.apache.struts.util.RequestUtils.populate(RequestUtils.java:1252) 
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processPopulate(RequestProcessor.java:821) 
org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:254) 
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1482) 
org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:525) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641) 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Below given the code segment where the exception occures.

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)     throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

    boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(httpRequest.getHeader("x-requested-with"));


    HttpSession httpSession = httpRequest.getSession(false);

    if(isAjax){
        if(isValidRequest(httpRequest, httpSession)){
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }else{
            returnInvalidMessage(httpRequest, httpResponse);
        }
    }else{
        chain.doFilter(request, response); /* Here is the exception occures */
    }
}
```

Exception occured in the below line

`chain.doFilter(request, response);`

Is any one have idea about this?

Comment: That's not the line throwing the `NullPointerException`. You have to understand what the stacktrace says. Please post the whole stacktrace.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I again checked it. But I found NPE thrown from the line at `com.incitesys.common.controller.SessionHandlingFilterAjax.doFilter(SessionHandlingFilterAjax.java:94)` . The line number 94 holds the chain.doFilter(request, response);

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
 String h = httpRequest.getHeader("X-Requested-With");
 boolean isAjax = (h == null?false:h.indexOf("XMLHttpRequest")>=0);
```

`isAjax` should be evaluated to `true` if this is an ajax request.

Comment: @sakura if this is not valid ajax request the form bean should not be populated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked with your logic. But the actual problem raised in the line `chain.doFilter(request, response);`. Something gone as `null` through the processing of this. `chain' is a reference variable of `javax.servlet.FilterChain`.

Comment: I got the solution. Actually the problem was not associated with the filter. I have added an `ActionForm` to the `session`. The `NPE` thrown when the ActionForm object removed from the session scope.

Comment: @SreerajTR If this answer helped you to solve your problem you can at least upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

if your project is running on tomcat,may be it's your project jar's problem.

> jsp-api.jar and servlet-api.jar

is conflict to tomcat's jar. so just delete both jar